# Cannot get history.push(url) to re-render page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

This comes up often, but no solution appears to work and I feel like I've exhausted every option I can think of, so I'm turning to here, believing this may be a slightly different scenario and not a duplicate. If there's an existing solution that works, I'm happy to be shown otherwise.

In my last create-react-app project, I had no problem rendering new pages with **Router** and **useHistory**. Using the exact same set up, I've run into the issue where `history.push(url)` changes the url in the address bar but the page doesn't re-render.

I'm using:

- React v17.0.2
- react-router-dom v5.3.0
- history v5.0.1 (also attempted
  on v4.10.1)

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import { Page } from './stories/Page';
import './App.css';

function App() {


    return (
            <Router>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/">
                        <Page homepage={true} />
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/project/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-z\-0-9]+)/([a-z\-0-9]+)/" render={urlprops =>
                        <Page projectID={urlprops.match.params[0]} homepage={false} />
                    } />
                    <Route path="/project/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-z\-0-9]+)/" render={urlprops =>
                        <Page projectID={urlprops.match.params[0]} homepage={false} />
                    } />
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        
    );

}

export default App;
```

**component-page.js**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useCallback } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'; 
import './menuitem.css';

export const Component = ({ url, ...props }) => {

    let history = useHistory();

    function handleItemClick(e) {
        history.push(url); // <- calls fine, tested with logging to console
    }
    ...
```

I've seen older solutions suggest passing history props through **Router** but in my last app I was able to use the set up above, and any level nested subcomponent would be able to call the **useHistory** hook and use push if they were set up like **component-page.js** above. Therefore I haven't shown the components between **App.js** and **component-page.js** on the belief that this should be irrelevant to `useHistory` functioning correctly.

#### Possibly relevant:

- If I enter the URLS in the address bar and hit return, **Router** renders the correct components, suggesting **Router** and **Switch** work fine with a freshly loaded page.
- I have React dev tools set up to blink on
  components when they re-render. After `history.push(url)` is called all
  components blink, though none re-render (visually, at least).
- Downgrading history to 4.10.1 seemed to fix a lot
  of the recent reports of this issue for others. I had no such luck. Apparently there was/is a bug with react-router-dom v5+ which meant history.push was not working with history v5+.
- I also placed a simple button component in the **Page** component that fired a request to history.push("string url here") with the same issue. It calls, address bar changes, page doesn't re-render. In my mind, this rules out it being some sort of nesting issue, which I didn't believe it was anyway.

---

## Update

Checking *history* in console after calling `history.push('url string')` shows the following under the location property. This looks like it's acting as intended (I'm only expecting pathname to match the url I tried to point to).

```
{
    "pathname": "url string",
    "search": "",
    "hash": "",
    "key": "ctks7v"
}
```

### Update 2

Possible progress. In my **Page** component I am calling fetch in a hook to catch any update, like so:

```
useEffect(() => {
    apiFetchProject(projectID);
}, []);
```

I'm now wondering if this is my problem? That this hook isn't seeing the url as a change that requires firing `apiFetchProject(projectID)`. The reason I say this is that console calls confirm this hook isn't being called here after my history.push, but a console call to the **Page** component *is* happening. I've tried calling the hook with any change in `props.location` but this comes back as undefined each time, which means the hook isn't called.

### Update 3

If, on **Page**, I use `import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";` with `let location = useLocation();` and let a hook look for a change in `location`, **Page** now successfully calls `fetch` after a `history.push` call. But something doesn't seem right about having to do this too? I feel I would have seen it as a standard instruction.

I'm having to add it to every component to see re-rendering of anything. The fetch in **Page** is stored as a state and passed down as a prop to subcomponents. A change of this state should automatically re-render all subcomponents that are passed it, as happens when the page is loaded.

Comment: I had a similar problem a while ago, and I think I solved it by "tricking" react into re-rendering by giving it a new key using a timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

instead of the url, put the path ('/home')

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the suggestion? url needs to be a dynamic variable and needs to match one of the Switch paths anyway. In terms of debugging, I've tried using strings instead of the url variable to exclude that being the issue (it wasn't).

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't answer the question at all - the question essentially boils down to _"I have a problem rendering new pages with Router and useHistory when calling history.push(url).  The url in the address bar changes but the page doesn't re-render."_